# Python - Split array into multiple arrays dependent on array values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have a list which needs to be split into multiple lists of differing size. The values in the original list randomly increase in size until the split point, where the value drops before continuing to increase. The values must remain in order after being split.

E.g.
Original list

```
[100, 564, 572, 578, 584, 590, 596, 602, 608, 614, 620, 625, 631, 70, 119, 
125, 130, 134, 139, 144, 149, 154, 159, 614, 669, 100, 136, 144, 149, 153, 
158, 163, 167, 173, 179, 62, 72, 78, 82, 87, 92, 97, 100, 107, 112, 117, 
124, 426, 100, 129, 135, 140, 145, 151]
```

After split:

```
[100, 564, 572, 578, 584, 590, 596, 602, 608, 614, 620, 625, 631]
[70, 119, 125, 130, 134, 139, 144, 149, 154, 159, 614, 669]
[100, 136, 144, 149, 153, 158, 163, 167, 173, 179]
[62, 72, 78, 82, 87, 92, 97, 100, 107, 112, 117, 124, 426]
[100, 129, 135, 140, 145, 151]
```

I have searched for a solution, finding `numpy.where` and `numpy.diff` as likely candidates, but I'm unsure how to implement.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ok. there's probably some fast and elegant solutions, but why did you not try to get this done with a simple `while` loop first?

Comment: Have a look at [Python's slice functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Using NumPy's `numpy.split` to have list of arrays as output -

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(a) # a is input list
out = np.split(arr,np.flatnonzero(arr[1:] < arr[:-1])+1)
```

**Approach #2**

Using loop comrehension to split the list directly and thus avoid `numpy.split` for efficiency purposes -

```
idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)<0)+1, len(a)]
out = [a[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
```

Output for given sample -

```
In [52]: idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)<0)+1, len(a)]

In [53]: [a[idx[i]:idx[i+1]] for i in range(len(idx)-1)]
Out[53]: 
[[100, 564, 572, 578, 584, 590, 596, 602, 608, 614, 620, 625, 631],
 [70, 119, 125, 130, 134, 139, 144, 149, 154, 159, 614, 669],
 [100, 136, 144, 149, 153, 158, 163, 167, 173, 179],
 [62, 72, 78, 82, 87, 92, 97, 100, 107, 112, 117, 124, 426],
 [100, 129, 135, 140, 145, 151]]
```

We are using `np.diff` here, which feeds in a list in this case and then computes the differentiation. So, a better alternative would be with converting to array and then using comparison between shifted slices of it instead of actually computing the differentiation values. Thus, we could get `idx` like this as well -

```
arr = np.asarray(a)
idx = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(arr[1:] < arr[:-1])+1, len(arr)]
```

Let's time it and see if there's any improvement -

```
In [84]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(1000,100)).cumsum(1).ravel().tolist()

In [85]: %timeit np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a)<0)+1, len(a)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.24 ms per loop

In [86]: arr = np.asarray(a)

In [87]: %timeit np.asarray(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.05 ms per loop

In [88]: %timeit np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(arr[1:] < arr[:-1])+1, len(arr)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 77 µs per loop

In [89]: 3.05+0.077
Out[89]: 3.127
```

So, a marginal improvement there with the shifting and comparing method with the conversion : `np.asarray(a)` *eating-up* most of the runtime.

Comment: By np do you mean numpy? You need an "import numpy as np", probably

Comment: How is the second version "list only"? You're still using two `numpy` functions.

Comment: @alexis Yup, you were right. Edited to have better words there.

Answer (score 4):

I know you tagged `numpy`. But here's a implementation without any dependencies too:

```
lst = [100, 564, 572, 578, 584, 590, 596, 602, 608, 614, 620, 625, 631, 70, 119, 
125, 130, 134, 139, 144, 149, 154, 159, 614, 669, 100, 136, 144, 149, 153, 
158, 163, 167, 173, 179, 62, 72, 78, 82, 87, 92, 97, 100, 107, 112, 117, 
124, 426, 100, 129, 135, 140, 145, 151]

def split(lst):
  last_pos = 0
  for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    if lst[i] < lst[i-1]:
      yield lst[last_pos:i]
      last_pos = i
  if(last_pos <= len(lst)-1):
    yield lst[last_pos:]

print([x for x in split(lst)])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use `numpy.diff` and `numpy.where`, you can try

```
a = numpy.array(your original list)
numpy.split(a, numpy.where(numpy.diff(a) < 0)[0] + 1)
```

Explanation:

`numpy.diff(a)` calculates the difference of each item and its preceding one, and returns an array.

`numpy.diff(a) < 0` returns a boolean array, where each element is replaced by whether it satisfies the predicate, in this case less than zero.  This is the result of `numpy.ndarray` overloading the comparison operators.

`numpy.where` takes this boolean array and returns the indices where the element is not zero.  In this context `False` evaluates to zero, so you take the indices of `True`.

`[0]` takes the first (and only) axis

`+ 1` You want to break off from after the indices, not before

Finally, `numpy.split` breaks them off at the given indices.